# how to move slider after closing the fancy box

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, opencart

I'm working on a opencart project. There i'm using fancy box plugin to show a video on the swiper slider. when i click the video button which on a slider, fancy box popping up and background slider getting stop. But after closing the fancy box, slider is not moving.

So please can someone suggest a solution to move the slider as usually after closing the fancy box ?

I have used this code to stop the slider moving when fancy box popped up

```
  $("#video").click(function() {
            .swiper-wrapper.noSwiping();
        });
```

Comment: Just to keep it running, are you trying to reload the page ?

Comment: I'm asking one more question, tittle has something to do with content?

Comment: @Rayon Yes. but is there are any other way ?

Comment: So, the real question would be - "How to re-enable slider after disabling"? But what slider are you using? And why you need it to stop moving - maybe you just need to disable "autoplay" or smth like that?

Comment: @Janis Yes .. how to re-enable after closing the fancy box . I'm using the swiper slider

Answer (score 0):

you can use this option for new version of fancybox to prevent swiper crashing.
fancybox places focus back on the trigger element after closing the gallery and sometimes carousel/slider scripts are sensitive to this feature.

```
Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="group"]', {
    infinite: false,
    backFocus: false,
    trapFocus: false,
    placeFocusBack: false,
});
```